# Android DocumentsProvider setNotificationUri() and notifyChange() ignored or wrong used

Tags: java, android

I writing an DocumentsProvider witch is rescale Imagefile. If a directory is loaded every Image get resacaled and the smaller version is stored in the cachedirectory. If a cached file is pretend the big file get be replaced.

Normally this should happen after every finished rescale but it isn't. The changes are only happen if i reenter the directory.

I don't know if i using the Cursor.setNotificationUri() wrong or if it isn't triggered.

queryChildDocument of DocumentsProvider:

```
@Override
public Cursor queryChildDocuments(String parentDocumentId, String[] projection,
                                  String sortOrder) throws FileNotFoundException {

    final MatrixCursor result = new MatrixCursor(projection != null ?
            projection : DEFAULT_DOCUMENT_PROJECTION) {
        @Override
        public Bundle getExtras() {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putBoolean(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_LOADING, true);
            return bundle;
        }
    };

    final File parent = getFileForDocId(parentDocumentId);

    for (File file : parent.listFiles()) {

        String id = getDocIdForFile(file);
        Uri updatedUri = DocumentsContract.buildChildDocumentsUri(
                "xxx.xxx.de.resizeprovider.documents", id);
        result.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), updatedUri);

        includeFile(result, null, file, updatedUri);

    }
    return result;
}
```

IncludeFile:

```
private void includeFile(MatrixCursor result, String docId, File file, Uri updatedUri)
        throws FileNotFoundException {
    if (docId == null) {
        docId = getDocIdForFile(file);
    } else {
        file = getFileForDocId(docId);
    }
    int flags = 0;

    if (file.isDirectory()) {
        //            flags |= Document.FLAG_DIR_PREFERS_GRID;
        if (file.isDirectory() && file.canWrite()) {
            flags |= Document.FLAG_DIR_SUPPORTS_CREATE;
        }
    } else if (file.canWrite()) {
        // If the file is writable set FLAG_SUPPORTS_WRITE and
        // FLAG_SUPPORTS_DELETE
        flags |= Document.FLAG_SUPPORTS_WRITE;
        flags |= Document.FLAG_SUPPORTS_DELETE;
    }

    final String displayName = file.getName();
    final String mimeType = getTypeForFile(file);

    if (mimeType.startsWith("image/")) {

        flags |= Document.FLAG_SUPPORTS_THUMBNAIL;
        File newfile = getFileForDocument(docId);;
        boolean resize = false;

        if (newfile.exists()){
            file = newfile;
        }
        else {
                new ResizeImageSimpleTask(file, newfile, resizeValue(), updatedUri).execute();       
            }

    }
    final MatrixCursor.RowBuilder row = result.newRow();
    row.add(Document.COLUMN_DOCUMENT_ID, docId);
    row.add(Document.COLUMN_DISPLAY_NAME, displayName);
    row.add(Document.COLUMN_SIZE, file.length());
    row.add(Document.COLUMN_MIME_TYPE, mimeType);
    row.add(Document.COLUMN_LAST_MODIFIED, file.lastModified());
    row.add(Document.COLUMN_FLAGS, flags);
    // Add a custom icon
    row.add(Document.COLUMN_ICON, R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
}
```

ResizeImageSimpleTask:

```
private class ResizeImageSimpleTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    File oldfile = null;
    File newfile = null;
    int imageSimpleValue = 0;
    Uri updatedUri = null;

    private ResizeImageSimpleTask(File oldfile, File newfile, int imageSimpleValue, Uri updatedUri){
        this.oldfile = oldfile;
        this.newfile = newfile;
        this.imageSimpleValue = imageSimpleValue;
        this.updatedUri = updatedUri;
    }
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {

        return resizeImageSimple(oldfile, newfile, imageSimpleValue);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        if (result ) {
            Log.i("MyProvider", "Resize success");

            getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(updatedUri, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Logcat is showing the Log.i("MyProvider", "Resize success"); so i get into onPostExecute() but the Content is not updated.

[DocumentsProvider.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/provider/DocumentsProvider.java) write that i can send a change notification to trigger a requery but i am not sure if this will call  queryChildDocuments(...) again or do something else.

Since i like to support Android 4.4+ i only can use api 19

What do i do wrong or what do i misunderstand?